# Big performance difference between Pytorch and Keras implementation in text classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, torchtext

I have implemented CNN in both Keras and Pytorch for a multi-label text classification task. Two implementations ended with two very different performances. CNN with Keras is noticeable outperform the CNN with Pytorch. Both used one layer CNN with kernel size 4.

The Pytorch version scores **0.023 for micro F1** and **0.47 for macro F1**. The model is shown as below (more details in colab notebook):

```
class CNN_simple(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, n_filters, filter_sizes, output_dim, 
                 dropout, pad_idx):       
        super().__init__()      
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, padding_idx = pad_idx)       
        self.conv = nn.Conv1d(in_channels = embedding_dim, 
                              out_channels = n_filters,
                              kernel_size = 4) # (N,C,L)

        self.fc = nn.Linear(n_filters, output_dim)     
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, text):      
        embedded = self.embedding(text)
        embedded = embedded.permute(0, 2, 1)
        conved = F.relu(self.conv(embedded))
        pooled = F.max_pool1d(conved, conved.shape[2]).squeeze(2)
        dropout = self.dropout(pooled)
        return self.fc(dropout)
```

The Keras version scores **0.70 for micro F1** and **0.56 for macro F1**. The model is shown as below (more details in colab notebook):

```
def get_model_cnn():
    inp = Input(shape=(MAX_TEXT_LENGTH, ))
    x = Embedding(MAX_VOCAB_SIZE, embed_size)(inp)

    x = Conv1D(embed_size, 4, activation="relu")(x)
    x = GlobalMaxPool1D()(x)
    x = Dense(6, activation="sigmoid")(x)

    model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=x)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

I assume there is something wrong with my Pytorch implementation. Any comment is appreciated. I have created [a colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jdjrOVVvodzjzqrRmIBIyUBrAG8o97Gy) for the full implementations of Pytorch and Keras. Feel free to copy and run it. Please enlighten me anything that I did wrong in the Pytorch implementations. Thanks.